# How to print data, retrieved from mongoDB database in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on a online shop project. I'm using Node.js, express.js and MongoDB with mongoose. I got the product information from the MongoDB database and sending them to the client side. In my case, I can get all these data in my client side but before sending, when I print them to the console in server side, it says undefined.

This is the products schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    productCategory: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productShortInformation: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productFullInformation: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productViews: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    productStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

and here is my Node.js code

```
router.get('/category/summary', function(req, res, next) {
    //getting my all products information
    var products = Product.find(function (err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error Happened'  + err);
            return res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            //ALL PRODUCT NAME IS SHOWN UNDEFINED
            //BUT WHEN I SEND THEM TO THE CLIENT, I GET PRODUCT NAME
            for(var product in docs) {
                console.log('Name: ' + product.productName);
            }

            res.render('shop/categorySummary', {
                products: docs  //sending these information to the client side
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When I try to print these product `name`, I get undefined. But in the client side I can print the product information.

I need to manipulate these data before sending them to the client side. So how can I print these product information to the server side(in console) before sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var product in docs) {
     console.log('Name: ' + docs[product].productName);
}
```

That should work

Comment: OMG, Thank you very much. It's working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BMShamsNahid On Stack Overflow we say thank you by [**accepting answers which helped us**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). There's a green checkmark next to the answer on the left which you tick :)